# R - coastline not fitting correctly in map plot

Tags: r, plot, maps, raster

I have this  [data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zdmihgl5vjkk2fv/precipitacion_mensual.nc?dl=0) it's GPCC 1x1 precipitacion data:   And to plot it I've done this:

```
library(RNetCDF)
library(raster)
library(pracma)
library(rasterVis)
library(colorRamps)
library(rgdal)


file <- open.nc("C:/Users/Ann/Downloads/precipitacion_mensual.nc")
var <- var.get.nc(file,"precip")
ro <- var[ , ,80]

ro_2 <- pracma::circshift(ro, c(180,2))

A <- raster(t(ro_2))

extent(A) <- c(-180, 180, -90, 90)

mex <- getData("GADM", country="MEX", level=0)

B <- crop(A,mex)
plot(B,main="Tit", xlab = "lon", ylab ="lat",col=matlab.like(n = 10),zlim = c(0, 500))

plot(mex, add =TRUE)
```

But when I plot it it comes out like this[image]
As you can see the coastline does not overlap properly on the map. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was in the `circshift` function I thought, by wirtting `circshift(variable,c(180,2))`, it will do the circular shift by 180 degrees along the second dimension.
However what this does is to shift 180 degrees the first dimension, and 2 degrees the second dimension.
I only have to put `circshift(var, c(179.5,0.5))` and the map comes out perfect.